# How Group JSON Array Data By multiple keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, group-by, grouping

How can I group JSON Array by multiple Keys in Nodejs.

Is there any solution with underscore or lodash (does not matter if its plain javascript)?

Array:

```
[{ key: '2017-1', y: 1, gkey: 'y' },
{ key: '2017-1', x: 1, gkey: 'x' }]
```

Expected Result :

```
[{ key: '2017-1', x: 1, y:1 }]
```

Comment: please show your attempt

Comment: usnig deepmerge, `merge.all(r);` r is the Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `Object.values`

```js
let arr = [ 
   { key: '2017-1', y: 1, gkey: 'y' },
   { key: '2017-1', x: 1, gkey: 'x' },
   { key: '2017-2', x: 1, gkey: 'x' },
];

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, {key,gkey,...r}) => {
  c[key] = c[key] || {key};
  c[key] = Object.assign(c[key], r);
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

If you cant use `Object.values` on your nodejs version, you can:

```js
let arr = [ 
   { key: '2017-1', y: 1, gkey: 'y' },
   { key: '2017-1', x: 1, gkey: 'x' },
   { key: '2017-2', x: 1, gkey: 'x' },
];

let temp = arr.reduce((c, {key,gkey,...r}) => {
  c[key] = c[key] || {key};
  c[key] = Object.assign(c[key], r);
  return c;
}, {});

let result = [];
for (let key in temp) result.push(temp[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help @JamalAbo

Comment: What do you recommend? First or second

Comment: If the first one is working with the version of your nodejs, then I recomend the first one :)

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly what you need, the `reduce` function could do what you need.

`reduce` call the function for each element of the array. `arr` is the result array who will be return by the reduce at the end. I check for each `elem` if it's in the `arr`. if not, I add it.

I did not test this code, but it should work

```
arrayOfData.reduce((arr, elem) => {
    let e = arr.find(el => el.key === elem.key);
    if(!e) {
        e = {key : elem.key}
        arr.push(e);
    }
    e[elem.gkey] = elem[elem.gkey];
    return arr;
}, [])
```

Comment: Its working for 2 keys only!, how can i add another key without any changes like, `{key:"2017-1", x:1,y:1,t:1}`

Comment: what do you mean? if I have : `[{key : '2017-1', x : 1, gkey : 'x'}, {key : '2017-1', y : 1, gkey : 'y'}, {key : '2017-1', t : 1, gkey : 't'}]`
it give me : `{key:"2017-1", x:1,y:1,t:1}`